# XtremeToolkit Menu, Ribbon issue [mfc]

Tags: c++, mfc, ribbon, menubar, toolkit

I manually added a Ribbon tab and called it from `CMainFrm::OnCreate()`
[image]

but it's strange that if I did `SetMenu(NULL)` the **line with Quick Access Bar** is there.

What is wrong here? Why there are 2 blue lines(I am not really sure how to call it) getting displayed?

(I was expecting to get only one blue line which is ribbon area)

[image]

code:

```
BOOL CMainFrame::CreateRibbon()
{

   CXTPCommandBars* pCommandBars = GetCommandBars();   



   CMenu menu;
   menu.Attach(::GetMenu(m_hWnd));
   SetMenu(NULL);

   // ribbon
   CXTPRibbonBar* pRibbonBar = 
   (CXTPRibbonBar*)pCommandBars->Add(_T("The Ribbon"),
   xtpBarTop, RUNTIME_CLASS(CXTPRibbonBar));
   
   if(!pRibbonBar){
    return FALSE;
   }

   pRibbonBar->EnableDocking(0);
   pRibbonBar->ShowQuickAccess(FALSE);


   // Home tab
   CXTPRibbonTab* pTapMenu = pRibbonBar->AddTab("홈");
   CXTPRibbonGroup* pMenuGroup = pTapMenu->AddGroup("first group");

   pMenuGroup->Add(xtpControlButton,IDS_RIBBON_A);


  }
```

Comment: What did you expect to happen instead? Also, please fix the formatting of your code. Make sure to use consistent indentation, and don't waste space (some people visit this site from a mobile device, where screen real estate is very precious).

Comment: @IInspectable editted! please take a look)

Comment: The solution was just commenting ```// LoadCommandBars(_T("CommandBars"))``` in ```CMainFrm::OnCreate``` before calling ```CreateRibbon()```

Comment: If the solution is to alter code we cannot see then that is a clear indication that you haven't provided a [mcve]. Mind you, that solution may be wrong; there's a difference between making a problem go away and solving an issue. But we have no way of telling.